# save Gtk# Textbuffer content to a file

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

Does Gtk# provide a possibility to write formatted text from a TextView / Textbuffer to a file?
What is the most reasonable file format to be used : XML, RTF, HTML?
In case there is nothing available:
Is there a simple way to step through the TextIter elements of a TextBuffer?
The only method I could imagine is:

```
for (i=0; i<TextBuffer.CharCount; i++){
  iter=TextBuffer.GetIterAtOffset(i);
  writeIterAndTagToFile(iter);
}
```

I hope there is a better method
thanks for the help
regards Harald

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can save the contents of a text buffer to a file, in GTK's internal serialization format - this guarantees that there can be a one-to-one correspondence between the text buffer and the serialized text. Check out `Gtk.TextBuffer.RegisterSerializeTagset`, `Gtk.TextBuffer.Serialize`, etc.

You can also write your own serialization converters and register them. I wrote one for RTF at one point; [Sourceforge page](http://sf.net/projects/osxcart). To get it to work in Mono, though, you will probably have to write a binding somehow. The latest version does work with GObject Introspection, but that's not available for Mono yet as far as I know. I'd offer to help you write a binding, but I know absolutely nothing about writing Mono bindings. If you do end up writing one, please let me know and I'll include it in the project.